# Auditing application's use of GPS

Tags: security, 4.3-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-4, gps, logging

There is an application on my phone that triggers the GPS at random intervals. The start of this polling doesn't correlate with any newly installed applications so I imagine a recent update or recently activated feature in an existing application is causing this behavior.

What options do I have to audit the GPS usage on my phone (Galaxy S4 - Verizon)?

Answer (score 0):

Android 4.4 allows you to view recent requests - this is probably the closest you can get...

This probably exists in prior versions too, I just don't have a device with JB to test it with. You get there from settings->location

Comment: It appears that at least on Verizon's image of 4.3 the settings app does not have this feature where you described it (or maybe at all?)